# Implementing a bounded Array in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to create a simple PHP game and ran into a problem. In this game, a player may stand on one of 18 positions. Position 1 is a start. The player "rolls a dice" - `rand(1,6)` - and may move that many positions either forward or backward. A simplified version of this "board" may look something like this:

```
$positions = array(
    1 => 'Start',
    2 => 'Some Field',
    3 => 'Some Field',
    4 => 'Some Field',
    5 => 'Some Field',
    ...
);
```

At this point I'm struggling how to write code to track the player's movement forward or backward within those fields while keeping the results bound to valid "positions"? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that implements [SPL](http://php.net/spl)'s `ArrayAccess`. As an starting point, here's an implementation of a ring buffer [I wrote](http://blog.joeysmith.com/articles/3.html) using SPL, just to get my hands dirty with the API.

```
<?php

class ringBuffer implements ArrayAccess {
    private $data;
    private $current = 0;



    public $size;

    public function __construct($sz=10) {
        $this->size = $sz;
        foreach(range(1, $sz) as $k=>$v) {
            /* s: whether this node is set; d: whether this node is "dirty" (has been read since it was last set); v: the value */
            $this->data[$k] = array('s' => false, 'd' => false, 'v' => NULL);
        }
    }

    private function offsetSet($key, $value) {
        $this->throwEx(array('Do not directly set indices in a %s, use push() instead', __CLASS__));
        return false;
    }

    public function offsetGet($key) {
        if (! is_int($key)) $this->throwEx(array("offset '%s' must be an integer, not %s", $key, gettype($key)));
        if ($key > $this->size) $key %= $this->size;
        if (!isset($this->data[$key])) return false;
        if (!$this->data[$key]['s']) return false;

        $this->data[$key]['d'] = false;
        return $this->data[$key]['v'];
    }

    public function offsetExists($key) {
        if (! is_int($key))
            throw new Exception();
        if ($key > $this->size)
            return $this->data[$key]['s'];
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key) {
        $this->data[$key]['s'] = false;
        $this->data[$key]['v'] = NULL;
    }

    private function throwEx() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if (is_array($args0)) {
            $msg = call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args0);
        }
        throw new Exception($msg);
    }

    public function push($value) {
        if ($this->current >= $this->size) $this->current %= $this->size;
        $this->data[$this->current] = array('s'=>true, 'd'=>true, 'v' => $value);
        $this->current++;
        return $value;
    }
}


$a = new ringBuffer(2);
$a->push("foo");
$a->push("bar");
$a->push("baz");

var_dump($a);

/* Will throw an exception because you can't directly set indices in a ringBuffer */

$a0 = 'foo';

/* Will throw an exception because ringBuffer indices must be ints */
var_dump($a['foo']);
var_dump($a[1.0]);
```

Doing this will allow you to build a lot more intelligence and behaviours into the data structure than a standard `array` will provide; for example, you could make it so that each 'field' has a list of adjacent fields which are possible moves from there ("if you're standing on 2, you can move to 6, 8, or 14 - but not 1, 3, or 7") and have that enforced BY the data structure, instead of littered through the code in every spot a move might come from.

Comment: `public function offsetSet()` I find this one completely useless, why is this into the public interface when there is no way using it hahaha...

Comment: Because the interface requires it.

Comment: it could be directed to push, instead of throwing unexpected exception (one could not be aware that it does not work?)

Comment: Could you please show quick example how to use it, to move within 1-18, from 14, 6 positions forward or from 4, 5 positions backward?

Comment: @RoyalBg Sure - that could have been done as well. In this case, I was specifically trying to translate a particular piece of code I found in the book [Python Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001674.do); it was just an illustration, never meant to actually be used in a real environment.

Comment: @user2668182 - The class above is actually a ring buffer, which I **don't** think is exactly what you want. I simply included it here as example of what can be performed using the [SPL](http://php.net/spl), so it would hopefully spark some ideas for you on how you can start to move some of your requiremets into your data structure implementation.